# UTC Now ( ) subtracts few hours (for PST time) in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am working at Azure Logic Apps, and I am trying to put the time stamp of PST time.

Initially, I was putting UTCNow(), but it stamped the time of server located.

But, I need to put the time stamp of Pacific Time Zone to the file name.

When I tried like this (**UTC-8**), it would **not** save it (error).

[image]

When I put it like **PTNow()**, Logic Apps is saved.

[image]

But, when I ran the Logic Apps, it still shows the time of UTCNow().

Comment: `convertTimeZone` should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#converttimezone

Comment: `convertFromUtc` should work as well `convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Pacific Standard Time')` or `convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Pacific Standard Time', 'yyy-MM-dd')` if you're only interested by the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by thomas , you can use either convertFromUtc or convertTimezone functions to covert the utc time to pst time in logic apps

- using [convertFromUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertfromutc):

```html
  convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'Pacific Standard Time')
```

- using [convertTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#converttimezone):

```html
convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Pacific Standard Time')
```

- Alternatively, you can use [subtractFromTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#subtractfromtime) function  to convert utc time zone to pst time zone

```html
 subtractFromTime(utcNow(),7,'Hour')
```